# Загружать графику в папку с ID объекта. models.ImageField

Tags: django

Есть строка модели

```
img_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/object/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)    
img_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/object/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

Из кода понятно, что при добавлении графического объекта в img_1 и img_2, он сохранится по пути photos/object/Год/Месяц/День.

Вопрос. Можно ли настроить загрузку графики таким образом, чтобы при сохранение, в путь, добавлялась не дата создания объекта а его ID?

Соответственно путь к графическим объектам приобретал вид: photos/object/ID_Объекта

Спасибо!

Comment: Вытаскивать последний id с бд и прибавлять 1

Comment: Отличная идея, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос был мне дан на Stackoverflow на английском. Если кому поможет вот ссылка 
[Django. When adding an image, create a folder corresponding to the object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249414/django-when-adding-an-image-create-a-folder-corresponding-to-the-object-id)

Или делаем следующие:

```
from datetime import date

def image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join([date.today().strftime('photos/%Y/%m/%d'), str(instance.id), filename])
```

в самой модели пишем:

```
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
```